# Vue watcher isn't triggered when watching a computed value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a component with a computed value and a watcher on that computed value. When the computed value is updated, the watcher sometimes isn't triggered.

I cannot provide a way to reproduce the issue because *iT wOrKs On My MaChInE* and in most cases (but not always) also works in our production build.

My code resembles this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      duckNames: ["Donald", "Mike"],
      llamas: [{ name: "Joe" }, { name: "Kamala" }],
      
      selectedAnimalName: "",
      lastSelectedLlamas: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedLlama() {
      return this.llamas.find(llama => llama.name === this.selectedAnimalName);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    selectedLlama(newLlama) {
      if (newLlama) {
        this.lastSelectedLlamas.unshift(newLlama);
      }
    },
    lastSelectedLlamas(newArr) {
      if (newArr.length > 2) {
        this.lastSelectedLlamas = newArr.slice(0, 2);
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async selectAnimal(name) {
      this.selectedAnimalName = name;
      this.isLoading = true;
      await this.fetchSomeData();
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    fetchSomeData() {
      return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button
    v-for="duckName in duckNames"
    @click="selectAnimal(duckName)"
  >
    {{ duckName }}
  </button>
  <br>
  
  <button
    v-for="llama in llamas"
    @click="selectAnimal(llama.name)"
  >
    {{ llama.name }}
  </button>
  <br>
  
  Selected animal: {{ selectedAnimalName }}<br>
  Last selected llamas: {{ lastSelectedLlamas }}<br>
  
  <span v-if="isLoading">
    Loading...
  </span>
</div>
```

In the example there's an array that the watcher fills with the last selected values. In the production build that *sometimes* doesn't happen. Debugging confirmed that the watch handler itself is not called.

My versions (idk what's relevant of these):

```
"dependencies": {
  "html-loader": "0.5.5",
  "vue": "2.6.11",
  "vue-color": "2.7.0",
  "vue-router": "3.1.3",
  "vuetify": "2.1.14",
  "vuex": "3.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.11.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.11.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "3.11.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "4.2.3",
  "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
  "vue-cli-plugin-html-replace": "1.3.0",
  "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "0.5.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11",
  "vuetify-loader": "1.4.3",
  "webpack": "4.41.2"
}
```

Comment: the watcher will not get triggered at all times...but only when  'selectedAnimalName' or 'illamas' gets changed

Comment: If I were you, I would set network mode in your dev tools to slow 3g, which probably would trigger the issue by delaying your fetch request. My guess is that Vue either does not handle the watcher modifying the value it is watching well, or you are running into the "Vue can't detect assignments to arrays and objects"-issue, which you can fix by using `this.$set` anywhere you do that. A different option is that the value for `selectedLlama` is changed twice in a tick, and the situation before and after the tick is unchanged for that variable.